# Flask: what happened to the script_info_option?

Tags: flask

I wanted it to add common app-configuration options such as `--config`, `--loglevel`, `--logfile`, etc. to my `flask.cli` group and read them from the `scriptinfo` in my app factory function.

The `@script_info_option` decorator was apparently removed after 0.11 with a cryptic commit message like "implementing simplified interface".

So... how do I do add app-factory-time configuration options now?

Answer (score 3):

Found out how you do it now:

1. Decorate your app factory with `@click.pass_context` so it gets the context as the first argument.
2. In the app factory, use `ctx.find_root().params` to get what was passed to the group.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [app factory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/) and pass arguments to it with the `@pass_script_info` decorator like so...

`manage.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import click
import config

from flask import Flask
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup, pass_script_info


def create_app(script_info):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    if script_info.config_mode:
        obj = getattr(config, kwargs["config_mode"])
        flask_config.from_object(obj)

    ...    
    return app


@click.group(cls=FlaskGroup, create_app=create_app)
@click.option('-m', '--config-mode', default="Development")
@pass_script_info
def manager(script_info, config_mode):
    script_info.config_mode = config_mode


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager()
```

`config.py`

```
class Config(object):
    TESTING = False

class Production(Config):
    DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user@localhost/foo'

class Development(Config):
    DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///app.db'

class Testing(Config):
    TESTING = True
    DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
```

Now in the command line (after running `pip install manage.py`) you can do `manage -m Production run`.